# What's is recommended for a To-Do List schema design for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema, database, nosql

With the main purpose of posting Tasks, displayed as either 'to-do' or 'done', how would one better structure a NoSQL DB of the following objects:

- Datetime Created *Not Null*
- Task ID *Not Null*
- Task ID as a Str *Not Null*
- Task Title *Not Null*
- Task Description
- Time &/or Date Due
- User *Not Null*

  - ID *Not Null*
  - ID as a Str *Not Null*
  - Name *Not Null*
  - Username *Not Null*
  - Location
  - Contacts Count
  - Date Created *Not Null*
  - UTC Offset *Not Null*
  - Time Zone *Not Null*
  - Geo-Enabled *Not Null*
  - Verified
  - Task Count *Not Null*
  - Language *Not Null*
- Geo-Location

  - Coordinates
  - Place
- Shared with Whom

  - ?
- Task Status

  - Marked Done
  - Auto-Moved to Done (because datetime-due is passed)
  - Labeled (True/False)
  - Edited
  - Edit Count
  - Edit Datetime
  - Deleted

Users can post an unlimited number of Tasks, and Tasks can be shared between users. How is this relationship best captured?

Tasks can be manually 'marked done', or 'auto-labeled' and 'auto-moved-to-done' because the date-time due is passed.

Edits & Deletes are to be recorded as well.

As a starting place, what are the upsides &/or downsides of the following schema (with scalability a prime focus):

```
{
   "created_at":"Day Mon ## 00:00:00 +0000 20##",
   "id":#####,
   "id_str":"#####",
   "title":"This is a title",
   "description":"The description goes here..",
   "date_due":"Day Mon ## 00:00:00 +0000 20##",
   "user":{
      "id":####,
      "id_str":"####",
      "name":"Full Name",
      "user_name":"Username",
      "location":"",
      "contacts_count":101,
      "created_at":"Day Mon ## 00:00:00 +0000 20##",
      "utc_offset":####,
      "time_zone":"Country",
      "geo_enabled":true,
      "verified":false,
      "task_count":101,
      "lang":"en",
   },
   "geo":?,
   "coordinates":?,
   "place":?,
   "shared_with":?,
   "moved_done":false,
   "marked_done":false,
   "edited":false,
   "deleted":false,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Edits & Deletes are to be recorded as well.

Do you only need to know *that* a task was altered, not how or by whom?

Otherwise, that will probably require versioning, i.e. for every `Task` there can be a number of `TaskVersions`. Alternatively, you could store the modification only - it depends on your needs. In particular, having many writers isn't easy because of locking - what if two people try to change the same object at 'the same time'? You might want to consider optimistic vs. pessimistic locking or mvcc. Be warned that the "Tasks can be shared between users" requirement must be designed carefully.

> As a starting place, what are the upsides &/or downsides of the following schema (with scalability a prime focus):

I guess that `user` refers to the user who logs in. I wouldn't denormalize that information. Suppose a user created a thousand tasks and adds a new contact. Now the `contacts_count` of 1000 documents must be updated or it will be wrong. Denormalize only what's really necessary, e.g. the `user_name`.

Depending on what kind of lists you show, you can also choose to only store the user id and actually fetch the user object whenever you need to display the user name. While complex joins aren't supported, doing a `$in` query on, say 50 or 100 ids (like you would have to query in a list of tasks) is pretty fast.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the concept of denormalizing with respect to the 'user_name' for example? Thanks for the concept checks.. For TaskVersions, would probably stick to only storing/updating modifications initially, though How & Whom would be records.. Fetching the user-object when necessary as a function of the user_id seems best, thanks